# Regexp. How to match word isn't followed and preceded by another characters

Tags: regex

I want to replace `mm` units to `cm` units in my code. In the case of the big amount of such replacements I use `regexp`.

I made such expression:

```
(?!a-zA-Z)mm(?!a-zA-Z)
```

But it still matches words like `summa`, `gamma` and `dummy`.

How to make up regexp correctly?

Comment: Is there a benefit to using lookahead/lookbehind instead of something like `\b[0-9+]\s?mm\b`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use character classes and change the first `(?!...)` lookahead into a lookbehind:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])mm(?![a-zA-Z])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RXCeUb/1)

The pattern matches:

- `(?<![a-zA-Z])` - a negative **lookbehind** that fails the match if there is an ASCII letter immediately to the *left* of the current location
- `mm` - a literal substring
- `(?![a-zA-Z])` - a negative **lookahead** that fails the match if there is an ASCII letter immediately to the *right* of the current location

**NOTE**: If you need to make your pattern Unicode-aware, replace `[a-zA-Z]` with `[^\W\d_]` (and use `re.U` flag if you are using Python 2.x).

Comment: since not all browsers support lookarounds, how can this be modified to avoid using lookaheads or lookbehinds but still get the desired result?

Comment: @Arsik36 In most cases, the lack of lookbehinds can be worked around using a bit of code and a slightly modified pattern. E.g. `(^|[^a-zA-Z])mm(?![a-zA-Z])`. But you might try word boundaries, `\bmm\b`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A newbie question as I learn regex, what part of regex specifies that there must NOT be ASCII letter immediately before mm? is it the ^ sign that specifies it? And also why did you include the OR sign, what edge case does that solve for?

Comment: @Arsik36 You are asking wrong questions. What is your input? What is your expected output? What is the programming environment?

Comment: I have the following 2 ursl: https://abc.abcdlocal.com:3000/ , and then https://abc.local.com:3000/ . I want to match the second case, but not the first one, because in the first url "local" is immediately preceded by a character or an integer. So, my use case is to not match url that contains a letter or an integer immediately before the word "local", but to match other instances, such as https://abc.local.com:3000/ or https://local.com:3000/ , for example. The programming environment is JavaScript

Comment: @Arsik36 Then a word boundary might be sufficient, `\blocal\b`, or a solution like I showed, `[^a-zA-Z\d]local\b`. You do not need any alternation since `local` is never expected at the start of string (`(^|[^A-Za-z])` matches either start of string or any one char other than an ASCII letter).

Comment: thank you for this information. I appreciate your help, happily upvoting your answer

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use lookaheads and lookbehinds, so if you wish to simplify your pattern you can try something like this;

```
\d+\s?(mm)\b
```

This does assume that your millimetre symbol will always follow a number, with an optional space in-between, which I think that in this case is a reasonable assumption.

The `\b` checks for a word boundary to make sure the `mm` is not part of a word such as `dummy` etc.

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/eYejFT/1)